# Vectorize a function whose arguments are different dimensions

Tags: numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

I am trying to create an array of Gaussians from their means and covariance matrices in NumPy.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

means = np.array([
        [ 1,  0],
        [ 2,  2],
        [ 3, -1]])
covs = np.array([
       [[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],
       [[9, 0],
        [0, 4]],
       [[4, 1],
        [1, 1]]])

# This works
gaussians = [multivariate_normal(mean, cov) for mean, cov in zip(means, covs)]
'''
[<scipy.stats._multivariate.multivariate_normal_frozen at 0x27ced7e9f60>,
 <scipy.stats._multivariate.multivariate_normal_frozen at 0x27ced7e92e8>,
 <scipy.stats._multivariate.multivariate_normal_frozen at 0x27ced7e92b0>]
'''

# This throws an error 
vec_gaussian = np.vectorize(lambda mean, cov: multivariate_normal(mean, cov))
gaussians = vec_gaussian(means, covs)
''' ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (3,2,2) '''

# Adding an axis gives singular matrix error (???)
gaussians = vec_gaussian(means[:, :, np.newaxis], covs)
''' LinAlgError: singular matrix '''
```

Is there any way to use `vectorize` or am i better off just using the for loop?

Comment: did you try adding another dimension to the object with shape (3,2) -> (3,2,1)? Maybe its just complaining about 2D vs 3D...
" or am i better off just using the for loop?" Just check it using %timeit (or similar) ;)

Comment: edited: i get `singular matrix` when nothing is singular

Comment: mmh. ok. thats not what were looking for ^^
looking at the definition of multivariate_normal for scipy and np, I do not see a possibility to not use the for loop.
Why don't you want to use it? How big / long is your means and covs? If it is not more than a few hundred / thousand, I dont think, this will be a bottleneck...

Comment: np.vectorize is slower, and is meant for scalar functions.  Read the docs carefully before attempting to use.

Comment: `zip(means, covs)` iterates on the first dimension of both arrays, which is size 3, producing size (2,) and (2,2) arrays.  Just for fun look at `list(covs)` to see what simple iteration on a multidimensional array does.  `np.vectorize` tries to `broadcast` the inputs against each other, and pass a tuple of scalars to your function.  There is a `signature` option that can change that, but that is even slower.

Comment: "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop." -- i just saw this. Always thought vectorization = speedup.